# How to change the thickness of flutter checkbox

Tags: flutter

After searching, I found a way to change the colors of the checkbox, but I did not find a way to change the thickness

**Is there any way other than using custom checkbox**

```js
 checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
        checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(kWhiteColor),
        fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
            return kPrimaryColor; // the color when checkbox is selected;
          }
          return Colors.grey
              .withOpacity(0.4); //the color when checkbox is unselected;
        }),
```

thanks

Comment: you mean the box or checkMark

Comment: if all you want is a box thickness then check [side](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxThemeData/side.html) property

Comment: thank you , side property is the solution , side: BorderSide(color: const Color(0xFF000000), width: .1),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flutter, the checkBox widget comes with a property named **side** .
Using the **side** property, one can easily change the check box's style, color, width, etc.

Code snippet example:

```
Checkbox(
        side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
              return const BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.red);
            }
            return const BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.green);
          },
        ),
        value: checkBoxValue,
        onChanged: (bool? updatedValue) {
          setState(() {
            checkBoxValue = updatedValue!;
          });
        })
```